# Getting livestreams from YouTube channel

Tags: c#, youtube-api, youtube-livestreaming-api

I am trying to keep track of the livestream viewers of a specific channel.
This is no problem when I have got the stream ID and use it manually.

However I want my program to be able to track upcoming livestream automatically. So I want to get the livestream ID from the channel for the next upcoming livestream. I have been looking through the documentation from the API, but I couldn't find anything.

What API call do I need to make?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot get the [`liveBroadcast`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts) or [`liveStream`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveStreams) object that does not belong to the user or channel you are authenticated as.  The `list` endpoint for each object requires you to authenticate as your own channel/user to retrieve your own live events only.

If you want to retrieve information on another channel's current live broadcasts, you have to use the standard [`Search/list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts/list) endpoint:

`part -> snippet`

`channelId` -> `[channelId of the channel/user with the live event]`

`eventType -> live`

`type -> video` (required when setting `eventType` to `live`)

```
HTTP GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId={channelId}&eventType=live&type=video&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```