# Youtube api get live broadcast ID with C#

Tags: c#, youtube-api

I want to tried to get youtube live broadcast id. But I can't get this.
Here is my code:

```
  UserCredential credential;
        Response.Write("AAA");
        var stream2 = new FileStream("c:/users/gislap/documents/visual studio 2012/Projects/youtube/secrect.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);


            credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream2).Secrets,
                new[] { YouTubeService.Scope.Youtube },
                "user",
                CancellationToken.None,
                new FileDataStore(this.GetType().ToString())
            );
            Response.Write("DDD");

        var youtubeService = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = this.GetType().ToString()
        });
        var my_video_request = youtubeService.LiveBroadcasts.ToString();

        Label1.Text = my_video_request.ToString();
```

Or any way to get all videos list?

Answer (score 0):

You may refer on this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34935505/5832311). If you want to retrieve information on another channel's current live broadcasts, you have to use the standard [`Search/list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts/list) endpoint:

> `part -> snippet`
>
> `channelId` -> `[channelId of the channel/user with the live event]`
>
> `eventType -> live`
>
> `type -> video` (required when setting `eventType` to `live`)
>
> ```
> HTTP GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId={channelId}&eventType=live&type=video&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
> ```

Also, based from this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts/list), try to use this HTTP request to return a list of YouTube broadcasts that match the API request parameters.

`GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/liveBroadcasts`

Here are examples which might help:

- https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/code_samples/
- https://github.com/search?l=C%23&q=LiveBroadcasts&type=Code&utf8=%E2%9C%93