# Getting broadcast id from channel id - youtube api v3

Tags: api, http, youtube-api

I need to know ID of livechat (or broadcast so I can get ID of livechat) based on video URL (I already have channel ID based on video URL). I tried following API endpoint like explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34904302/getting-livestreams-from-youtube-channel/34935505#34935505).

Here's what I input to URL address/what I request with GET:

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId=UChs0pSaEoNLV4mevBFGaoKA&eventType=live&type=video&key=AIzaSy...

And that's the output:

```json
{
  "kind": "youtube#searchListResponse",
  "etag": "HThuNpak09_KEjLGVv8ha1kgI3A",
  "regionCode": "PL",
  "pageInfo": {
    "totalResults": 2,
    "resultsPerPage": 5
  },
  "items": [
    {
      "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
      "etag": "ui0jIAKvsHNSKCOhqlbrgXGcH4o",
      "id": {
        "kind": "youtube#video",
        "videoId": "36YnV9STBqc"
      },
      "snippet": {
        "publishedAt": "2020-03-28T00:19:07Z",
        "channelId": "UChs0pSaEoNLV4mevBFGaoKA",
        "title": "The Good Life Radio • 24/7 Live Radio | Best Relax House, Chillout, Study, Running, Gym, Happy Music",
        "description": "The Good Life is live streaming the best of Relaxing & Chill House Music, Deep House, Tropical House, EDM, Dance & Pop as well as Music for Sleep, Focus, ...",
        "thumbnails": {
          "default": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/36YnV9STBqc/default_live.jpg",
            "width": 120,
            "height": 90
          },
          "medium": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/36YnV9STBqc/mqdefault_live.jpg",
            "width": 320,
            "height": 180
          },
          "high": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/36YnV9STBqc/hqdefault_live.jpg",
            "width": 480,
            "height": 360
          }
        },
        "channelTitle": "The Good Life Radio x Sensual Musique",
        "liveBroadcastContent": "live",
        "publishTime": "2020-03-28T00:19:07Z"
      }
    },
    {
      "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
      "etag": "kRiJkYyDYEITPVKTY4ZwhzM2LeE",
      "id": {
        "kind": "youtube#video",
        "videoId": "wKOEl_vwPSo"
      },
      "snippet": {
        "publishedAt": "2020-04-29T15:57:15Z",
        "channelId": "UChs0pSaEoNLV4mevBFGaoKA",
        "title": "Deep House Radio • 24/7 Live Radio | Vocal Deep House &amp; Chill House Music",
        "description": "Deep House Radio • 24/7 Live Radio | Vocal Deep House & Chill House Music Listen to the Playlist on Spotify: ...",
        "thumbnails": {
          "default": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/wKOEl_vwPSo/default_live.jpg",
            "width": 120,
            "height": 90
          },
          "medium": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/wKOEl_vwPSo/mqdefault_live.jpg",
            "width": 320,
            "height": 180
          },
          "high": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/wKOEl_vwPSo/hqdefault_live.jpg",
            "width": 480,
            "height": 360
          }
        },
        "channelTitle": "The Good Life Radio x Sensual Musique",
        "liveBroadcastContent": "live",
        "publishTime": "2020-04-29T15:57:15Z"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Do and I cannot find broadcast id, or chat id here. Do you guys know some kind of workaround, or fix for this? Do you know what changed since answer that I linked was posted?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [YouTube Data API v3](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3) [Videos: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) endpoint you can retrieve the live chat id of a livestream, more precisely you will find it in `item/liveStreamingDetails/activeLiveChatId` of https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=liveStreamingDetails&id=VIDEO_ID&key=API_KEY

Then thanks to [YouTube Streaming API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/getting-started) [LiveChatMessages: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveChatMessages/list) endpoint you can retrieve the livestream chat messages thanks to https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/liveChat/messages?part=snippet,authorDetails&liveChatId=LIVE_CHAT_ID&key=API_KEY